# Change year in pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a large amount of time-series data where I want to change all the years within a certain range to year 1900 (for example). My MWE is

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['alice','bob','charlie'],
    'date_of_birth': ['10/25/2005','10/29/2002','01/01/2001']})

# convert to type datetime
df['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_birth'])
print(df)

df['date_of_birth'] = df['date_of_birth'].mask(df['date_of_birth'].dt.year > 2000, \
                         df['date_of_birth'] - pd.to_timedelta(100, unit='y') + \
                         pd.to_timedelta(12, unit='h'))
print(df)
```

This method changes the year, as well as months and days. Is there a way to only change the year and leave everything else as is?

Comment: Why do you add `pd.to_timedelta(12, unit='h')`? You need that or it's a test?

Comment: you're right, that bit isn't necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`date.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace):

```
s = df["date_of_birth"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(year=1900))
df["date_of_birth"] = np.where(df["date_of_birth"].dt.year > 2000, s, df["date_of_birth"])
```

```
      name date_of_birth
0    alice    1900-10-25
1      bob    1900-10-29
2  charlie    1900-01-01
```